# Laplace transform of $tf'(t)$

Tags: laplace-transform

I know that $\mathcal{L}(tf'(t)) = -\frac{d}{ds}\mathcal{L}(f'(t))$
and that this $= -\frac{d}{ds}(sF(s) - f(0))$ but the solution says that this becomes $-F(s) - F'(s)$ and I can't figure out why $\frac{d}{ds}f(0) = sF'(s)$. Shouldn't it be $0$ ?

Comment: It should and indeed it is :)

Answer (score 2):

Notice that 
$$-\frac{d}{ds}(sF(s)-f(0))=-\frac{d}{ds}sF(s)+\frac{d}{ds}f(0)=-F(s)-sF'(s)+0=-F(s)-sF'(s)$$